# Create instance methods in JS that apply function with a dot

Tags: javascript, node.js

We have a built in function in Javascript.

```
34.toString()
```

How can I create a function like this? **What is the actual name of this type?**

I can create a function like

```
 function f(d){
     ...
   }
```

And call it as `f(5)` or something.

But how do we create something like,

```
5.f()

    var user = {
    email: "data@g.com"
    ,
    password: "password"
};

function g (){
    var data = this;
    return data.email;

}

console.log(user.g());
```

This does not work

Comment: `a.f()` is basically equivalent to `f.call(a)`. Note that extending built-in prototypes is frowned upon because it can lead to all sorts of issues with code that traverses object properties. It's better to create a simple function and accept the value as argument (as you have with `f`).

Comment: @FelixKling, this does not work this way. Can you see the issue in my updated code? The error is that $g$ is not a function

Comment: It should be `f.call(user)`. `user.g()` will only work if you do `user.g = g;` beforehand. I didn't mean that those are interchangeable, only that they produce the same result.